# Mount options do not match with working configuration

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

In essence, I'm willing to configure one of my hard drives on Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried a few lines in /etc/fstab yet somehow it changes on startup from rw to ro.
Current configuration:

```
UUID=1CE04C38E04C1A82 /mnt/1CE04C38E04C1A82 ntfs defaults,rw,windows_names,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

in mount a record about this drive looks like this:

```
/dev/sda7 on /mnt/1CE04C38E04C1A82 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)
```

And also I've tried:

```
UUID=1CE04C38E04C1A82 /mnt/1CE04C38E04C1A82 auto rw,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

UUID=1CE04C38E04C1A82 /mnt/1CE04C38E04C1A82 ntfs-3g  auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,utf8  0  0

UUID=1CE04C38E04C1A82 /mnt/1CE04C38E04C1A82 ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0

UUID=1CE04C38E04C1A82 /mnt/1CE04C38E04C1A82 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,permissions 0 0
```

Anyway, it keeps setting as ro and for now I'm out of options

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  It's a NTFS partition, so I'm guessing is also used by windows.  Did windows do a clean shutdown (and not hibernate).  If you have fast-boot enabled, it's really a form of hibernation and thus you didn't shutdown; the file system is left in an inconsistent state (data is saved in the hibernate file and not written to the file-system) and Ubuntu uses it as read-only for safety purposes.